# How do I hide and/or unhide the TabViewItem component in NativeScript?

Tags: typescript, nativescript

How do I display and hide a component in NativeScript using the tag TabViewItem? I want to be able to have the option to display and/or hide the tab.

```
<TabView>
    <TabView.items>
        ...
        <TabViewItem title="LOGOFF">
            <TabViewItem.view >
                ...
            </TabViewItem.view>
        </TabViewItem>
    </TabView.items>
</TabView>
```

Below are examples of what I have tried:

```
<TabView>
    <TabView.items>
        ...
        <TabViewItem title="LOGOFF" [visibility]="settings.showLogin ? 'collapsed' : 'visible'">
            <TabViewItem.view >
                ...
            </TabViewItem.view>
        </TabViewItem>
    </TabView.items>
</TabView>
```

With CSS:

```
<TabViewItem title="LOGOFF" class="hideTab">

.hideTab{
    display: none;
}
```

and

```
<TabViewItem title="LOGOFF" [class.hideTab]="true">
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you using apple software?  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TabView/Tasks/ManagingTabViewItems.html

Comment: No, Jeremy...  thanks for help.

Comment: can you provide more details?  How is this rendered in the page?  Is this XML that is converted to HTML?

Comment: @JeremyRayBrown this is NativeScript, take a look:  https://www.nativescript.org/

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks a little bit strange. What are you trying to achieve with the `[visibility]` and `[class.hideTab]`?

Anyways, the `visibility` property is what you want to use to control visibility.

E.g. this will hide a component:

```
<Component visibility="collapse" />
```

As with any other value, this can be set from a variable set on your binding context. E.g. if you have `isShown` as a boolean variable on your binding context, it'll control the visibility:

```
<Component visibility="{{ isShown ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }} />
```

Comment: Hi... I'm following some examples. About collapse or collapsed, has an issue open to resolve this discrepancy in NativeScript.

`Warning: Currently NativeScript is inconsistent with the CSS spec, as the CSS spec defines visibility: collapse, and NativeScript uses visiblity: collapsed. I have an issue open to resolve this discrepancy.` Font >> [link](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/06/05/nativescript-showing-and-hiding-elements/)
I think the component should be involved with any tag that enables visibility, just do not know which.

Comment: You should use 'collapse'. This was changed as of June 16 2015 ( https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/333 ). 'collapsed' is still available because of compatibility reasons, but it's deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: how can i achieve same with angular 2 ?? Any Help